# How do I select dataframe rows using PuLP for linear optimisation

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, data-science, pulp

I am trying to solve the following problem:

I have a pandas dataframe df with multiple columns. I want to find values a and b to maximise the sum of column 'result' divided by the number of selected rows from the dataframe where a and b are used to select rows of the dataframe using the following constraints:

```
df['x'] >= a & df['y'] <= b
2.5 <= a <= 20
0.05 <= b <= 0.35
```

I tried using PuLP, but never worked with it before and therefore am stuck.
Here's a sample code for the problem and how I tried to solve it:

```
import pandas as pd
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [2.94, 10.33, 8.67, 10.18, 2.82], 'y': [0.34, 0.21, 0.06, 0.24, 0.28], 'result': [-0.5, 9.55, 13.59, -0.2, 11.59]})
model = LpProblem(name='find_values', sense=LpMaximize)
a = LpVariable(name='a', lowBound=2.5, upBound=20)
b = LpVariable(name='b', lowBound=0.05, upBound=0.35)

# add constraints
model += a <= 20
model += b <= 0.35
# Set the objective
model += lpSum(
    df[(df['x'] >= a) & (df['y'] <= b)]['result']) / len(
    df[(df['x'] >= a) & (df['y'] <= b)])

print(model)
model.solve()
# Get the results
print(model.status)
print(LpStatus[model.status])
print(model.objective.value())
print(a.value())
print(b.value())
```

Once this is run, the following output is shown:

```
find_values:
MAXIMIZE
6.806
SUBJECT TO
_C1: a <= 20

_C2: b <= 0.35

VARIABLES
2.5 <= a <= 20 Continuous
0.05 <= b <= 0.35 Continuous

1
Optimal
Objective value
None
2.5
0.05
```

For me it looks like the mistake is in the objective function, since the model has a fixed value there indicating the code is already evaluated.
However, I have no idea, how I have to formulate it to work or if this is even possible with PuLP.

Comment: This is an essentially discrete problem that is not suited to linear programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use pulp variables to build the objective expression. However, because your objective expression can't be expressed by pulp variables, you need to reformulate the problem and solve it as a mixed-integer program.

Alternatively, you can keep the objective (which doesn't seem to be differentiable) and use a *black-box* optimization by means of `scipy.optimize.dual_annealing`. But please be aware that this approach doesn't guarantee a local maximum:

```py
from scipy.optimize import dual_annealing

def objective(ab):
    a, b = ab
    mask = (df.x >= a) & (df.y <= b)
    if (mask == False).all():
        return -1000.0
    else:
        vals = df[mask].result.values
        return np.sum(vals) / vals.size

# transform the maximization problem into a minimization problem
res = dual_annealing(lambda ab: -1.0*objective(ab), bounds=((2.5, 20.0), (0.05, 0.35)))
```

This yields a solution (a=6.55, b=0.13) with objective value 13.59.